# Is there an issue with this microsoft site?

Tags: internet-explorer

I am trying to fix a friends computer (Had malware etc). I have used Malwarebytes to do that. Anyway now I want to update IE.

I went too:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/default.aspx >> Downloads >> Internet Explorer (https://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/internet-explorer/download-ie-MCM) Which is giving me some error. Wondering if this is local to me, or if it is happening to other people.

Sometimes it gives me the option to accept an insecure certificate.

Comment: "some error" being what exactly?

Comment: You may try this link and see if it works: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an SSL error. The host name of the server does not match what is being advertised in the SSL certificate.

You can just visit the non-HTTPS version of the site or ignore the error.

Comment: I was nervous because the computer had lots of malware n wondered if the URL was being hijacked.

Comment: @user2421464 Given that the certificate they provide is issued to `*.windows.microsoft.com`, it's probably safe to be trusted. It just doesn't match the given domain. It would only match subdomains of it. But the certificate itself is valid.

Comment: Is that odd though for MS to have an error like that just following there own url's?